# Is passing const reference to a temporary string object safe in C++?

Tags: c++

Consider function f

```
void f(const std::string& s) {
    ...
}
```

Is it safe to call f with a fixed string like the following:

```
f("abc");
```

Comment: It is neither safe nor unsafe. It may or may not do what you want, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: @PeteBecker What kind of things can be dangerous? I do not try to change s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lifetime of the `std::string` implicitly constructed from `"abc"` is until the call to `f()` ends. So long as you aren't keeping that reference around somewhere else after `f()` ends, it is perfectly safe.

```
std::string const *pstr;

void f(std::string const &s)
{
    s.length(); // safe. s has an instance backing
                // it for the lifetime of this function.

    pstr = &s; // still technically safe, but only if you don't
               // dereference pstr after this function completes.
}

f("abc");

pstr->length(); // undefined behavior, the instance
                // pstr pointed to no longer exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't store a reference or a pointer to the argument somewhere and hope that it is still around once you returned from the function, it should be OK: when the function is called, a temporary `std::string` is created which is around for the time the function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe if you don't use it after the function returns.

Because of this, it's also safe to use it to initialize another string object (before the function returns), even if this string object lives longer (and is used longer).